# Is there any possible way of having an object and an array of objects with the same name and with the same class definition?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am retrieving data from a dynamically updating json. It contains an object of type X at some time, and an array of X type objects at some other time. I need a parent class Y that could work in any of the above situation. And also the object name: x remains the same.

```
class Y
{
    public X x { get; set; }
    public X[] x { get; set; }
}
class X
{
    public int a { get; set; }
}
```

This shows an error: the type Y already contains a definition for x
Is there any possible way to do it??

Comment: What does that even mean? What would obj.x resolve to?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting the error is C# does not allow a variable of two types with the same name.

You can not declare

```
SomeMethod()
{
    int x = 0;
    string x = "something";
}
```

If I were you I would probably do the following.

```
 class Y
{
   public List<X> listOfX{get; set;}
}
class X
{
    public int a { get; set; }
}
```

You can have a list. If there is only one element, then there is a list of size 1 element.

Answer (score 0):

The C# spec says that members of a type must have a unique name (which I assume is to prevent ambiguous member references). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691137(v=vs.71).aspx , specifically:

> **Because every member of a namespace or type must have a unique name**, it follows that the  fully qualified name of a namespace or type is always unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dynamic keyword, if you need an attribute named x to return a single value of type X at one time, and an array of X at another.

```
class Y
{
    public dynamic x { get { return IfMonday() ? new X() : new X[100]; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but its not helping me.   
Is there any way in c# to check whether a variable is an object or an array?? So that I can use it instead of IfMonday().... 

Something like php's bool is_array() ??

Comment: Do you mean bool b = (x is T[]); ?